# Codeigniter error logs show a 404 non-existing images directory...need to worry?

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I've recently started logging my errors through codeIgniter. Since doing so, I have noticed a lot of 404 errors for directories that don't exist. For example:

ERROR - 2010-05-15 21:06:26 --> 404 Page Not Found --> someController/images

Where someController is, obviously, a controller. The problem is, there are no functions within that controller called images, nor are there any links to a directory by that name. Could this be that someone is trying to hack my site? If so, do I need to worry? If not, why is this happening? Thanks, and forgive the newby-ness.

Comment: I forgot to mention....it happens several times within a few seconds, then may not happen for several days...if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be a problem with relative links? I'm yet to hear of an exploit looking for non-existent image directories, though that kind of relies on the type of site you operate.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that....that could definitely be it...any ideas on how to identify where it is so I can make it absolute?

Comment: I'd imagine that the most likely would be the views of someController since I'd imagine you would have accidentally typed `images` instead of `/images`. Other then that, I'd try an intelligent project search.

Comment: Great! Well I very much appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

**Looks like a bot**

Not all bots/browsers are intelligent about following links.(like the ones in css).
Some bots try the wrong URL to retrieve a resource.

De burst of error errors also indicate the usage pattern of a webcrawler.

**I wouldn't worry** about it from a security standpoint.

You might want to try out a dead-link test tools to help identify broken link.
But some bots just dont get it.

Errors like "404 /phpMyAdmin/script/setup.php" **are** attempts to hack your site, but these are **failed** attempts.

Comment: Cool...thanks for the reassurance. Any recommended dead-link tools?

Comment: On linux there is gURLChecker and online there is http://validator.w3.org/checklink.

Answer (score 0):

you have a wrong link

for example

**wrong**
"< link type="image/x-icon" **href="images/logo.png/>** "

the logs will appear a message
ERROR - 2010-05-15 21:06:26 --> 404 Page Not Found --> someController/images

**correct**
"< link type="image/x-icon" **href="< ?php echo base_url() ? >images/logo.png/>** "

sorry my english is not good